# C: Detect third level domain in URL

Tags: c, regex, string, search

I'm dealing with the following issue. I'd like to check a valid URL whether it contains certain patterns, specifically, for instance, whether it has a third-level domain. I need something like this, except that strstr doesn't accept regular expressions such as * (asterisk)... Can you help?

```
if (strstr(url, ".*")) {
      printf("third domain: yes\n");
} else {
      printf("third domain: no\n"); };
```

Comment: So, you need regular expression library?  Is that it?

Comment: `strstr()` does only do exact matching. For regular expressions see `man regex` & friends.

Comment: If you are going the regex way, this "regex" will always return "yes" for all valid strings (they all start with zero or more periods).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `POSIX regex`  or [PCRE libary](http://www.pcre.org/)

The `GNU C Library` supports two interfaces for matching regular expressions. One is the `standard POSIX.2 interface`, and the other is what the `GNU C Library has had for many years`.

Both interfaces are declared in the header file `regex.h`. If you define `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`, then only the `POSIX.2 functions, structures, and constants are declared`.

With the help of these library functions you can check whether regular expression is matching the given string or not.

```
reti = regexec(&regex, url, 0, NULL, 0);
        if( !reti ){
                puts("Match");
        }
```

Further You can replace matches.

[Example of POSIX regex in C](http://www.peope.net/old/regex.html)